# How to protect my idea after the 12 month PPA expiry?

Tags: ppa

how do I continue to protect my idea after my 12 month PPA expires?
The USPTO states “A provisional application for patent has a pendency lasting 12 months from the date the provisional application is filed. The 12-month pendency period cannot be extended.”
In this case it seems I need to file a non-provisional. Is there any way to protect my provisional patent without incurring the cost of a non-provisional?

Comment: Possibilities - not recommendations: refile  provisional content as non provisional , if not yet disclosed refile provisional.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeWhite - “disclosed” meaning publicly? Or does talking with potential investors, manufacturers, etc constitute publicly disclosed?

Comment: Disclosed means publicly. I would highly recommend anyone else you disclose to sign a confidentiality agreement.

Comment: Even one person who is not under an agreement of confidentiality is public. It could be verbal. Most professional investors will *not* agree to confidentiality.